# libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tensorflow, cublas, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install tensorflow in `Ubuntu 18.04`. CUDA and cudnn tests all pass. The title of this question is my error when testing the tensorflow installation. I saw the same question asked for `Ubuntu 16.04`, but the answers were not immediately helpful. One answer suggested the use of strace, but I do not understand the output.

Here is my full error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/home/dma/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Where is libcublas.so.9.0 and is that folder in your PATH?

Comment: libcublas.so.9.0 is in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.   In the end, I just rolled back to Ubuntu 16.04 and all is well. I am not certain, but my interpretation is that Tensorflow is not yet fully integrated with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: That's not really an answer, its probably something you didn't consider or a small mistake.

Answer (score 2):

append:

```
export  PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to `/etc/profile`

then, reboot.

If you dont have softlink `cuda` linked with `cuda-9.0` in `/usr/local`, just create one softlink at first or modify the above path to what you have.

Comment: Update: I had all the paths added in my .bashrc file and the appropriate softlink.  In the end, I just rolled back to Ubuntu 16.04 and all is well.  I am not certain, but my interpretation is that Tensorflow is not yet fully integrated with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I have this same issue after upgrading ubuntu. @user3877654 are you still runnig the downgraded version?

Comment: @rtl Yes, I am still running on 16.04 with no significant issues.  Eventually I suspect I will have to upgrade, but for now it was the quickest way for me to be functional.  Best of luck to you!  Have you gotten it to work on 16.04 yet?

Answer (score 0):

Using a virtual environment to isolate package installation from the system, as it is recommendend in the tensorflow installation guide, fixed it for me.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip